# Getting Enum value as Null in SOAP Response using AXIS in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, axis, soap-client

I am getting null value for Enum in SOAP Response when server is sending the proper response but when i looked into that enum as returning the value(checked in setter()). and also Server returning the enum value as well in response.

As i couldn't find the issue why the field is coming as null in client SOAP Response even the enum is returning the value(checked in setter()).

Please find response output for this field as shown below from SOAP Client response:

```
<ns3:AppSource/>
```

Please find the code details as below:

```
@XmlType(name = "AppSourceSelector")
@XmlEnum
public class AppSourceSelector implements java.io.Serializable {
    private java.lang.String _value_;
    private static java.util.HashMap _table_ = new java.util.HashMap();

    // Constructor
    protected AppSourceSelector(java.lang.String value) {
        _value_ = value;
        _table_.put(_value_,this);
    }

    public static final java.lang.String _SCREEN = "SCREEN";
    public static final java.lang.String _API = "API";
    public static final java.lang.String _FILE = "FILE";
    public static final AppSourceSelector SCREEN = new AppSourceSelector(_SCREEN);
    public static final AppSourceSelector API = new AppSourceSelector(_API);
    public static final AppSourceSelector FILE = new AppSourceSelector(_FILE);

    public java.lang.String getValue() { return _value_;}

    public static AppSourceSelector fromValue(java.lang.String value)
          throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException {
        System.out.println("value:>>>>>>"+value);
        AppSourceSelector enumeration = (AppSourceSelector)
            _table_.get(value);
        if (enumeration==null) throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException();

        System.out.println("enumeration:>>>>>>"+enumeration);
        return enumeration;
    }
    public static AppSourceSelector fromString(java.lang.String value)
          throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException {
        return fromValue(value);
    }
    public boolean equals(java.lang.Object obj) {return (obj == this);}
    public int hashCode() { return toString().hashCode();}
    public java.lang.String toString() { return _value_;}
    public java.lang.Object readResolve() throws java.io.ObjectStreamException { return fromValue(_value_);}

    public static org.apache.axis.encoding.Serializer getSerializer(
           java.lang.String mechType, 
           java.lang.Class _javaType,  
           javax.xml.namespace.QName _xmlType) {
        return 
          new org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.EnumSerializer(
            _javaType, _xmlType);
    }
    public static org.apache.axis.encoding.Deserializer getDeserializer(
           java.lang.String mechType, 
           java.lang.Class _javaType,  
           javax.xml.namespace.QName _xmlType) {
        return 
          new org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.EnumDeserializer(
            _javaType, _xmlType);
    }
    // Type metadata
    private static org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc typeDesc =
        new org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc(AppSourceSelector.class);

    static {
        typeDesc.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("com.*.*", "AppSourceSelector"));


    }
    /**
     * Return type metadata object
     */
    public static org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc getTypeDesc() {
        return typeDesc;
    }

}
```

### Application Entity.java

```
public class ApplicationEntity implements Serializable
{

    @XmlElement(name = "AppSource", required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "string")
    private com.*.*.AppSourceSelector appSource;

    // Type metadata
    private static org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc typeDesc =
        new org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc(ApplicationEntity.class, true);

    static {
        typeDesc.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("com.*.*", "ApplicationEntity"));

        org.apache.axis.description.ElementDesc elemField = new org.apache.axis.description.ElementDesc();

        elemField.setFieldName("appSource");
        elemField.setXmlName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("com.*.*", "AppSource"));
        elemField.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("com.*.*", "AppSourceSelector"));
        elemField.setNillable(false);
        typeDesc.addFieldDesc(elemField);

    }

    /**
     * Return type metadata object
     */
    public static org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc getTypeDesc() {
        return typeDesc;
    }

    /**
     * Get Custom Serializer
     */
    public static org.apache.axis.encoding.Serializer getSerializer(
           java.lang.String mechType, 
           java.lang.Class _javaType,  
           javax.xml.namespace.QName _xmlType) {
        return 
          new  org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanSerializer(
            _javaType, _xmlType, typeDesc);
    }

    /**
     * Get Custom Deserializer
     */
    public static org.apache.axis.encoding.Deserializer getDeserializer(
           java.lang.String mechType, 
           java.lang.Class _javaType,  
           javax.xml.namespace.QName _xmlType) {
        return 
          new  org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanDeserializer(
            _javaType, _xmlType, typeDesc);
    }

}
```

Can anyone please help on this.

Comment: If your response XML node is `<ns3:AppSource/>`, then server is not returning proper response. It must be something like `<ns3:AppSource>SCREEN OR API OR FILE</ns3:AppSource>`. Check your server response.

Comment: The server is returning the value as "SCREEN" but that value is not mapping to the  "AppSource".Can you please help on this. @RedBoy